# Build tool for HTML Template developer. Any?

Tags: javascript, html, css, templates, build-tools

I am finding a build tool that help me to build the html template files to complete html. Like this:

**header.tmp**

```
<html>
<head><title>Hello world</title></head>
<body>
```

**footer.tmp**

```
<script></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.tmp**

```
{{header.tmp}}
<div>Hello world!</div>
{{footer.tmp}}
```

**otherpage.tmp**

```
{{header.tmp}}
<div>This is another page</div>
{{footer.tmp}}
```

And then I use a command to build the template, for example:

```
> htmltemplatebuilder ./
    Building... index.html
    Building... otherpage.html
```

Then I get the **index.html** and **otherpage.html** with header, body and footer. You got the idea.

I believe there is a tool like that, but I just cannot find out.

Please help, thanks a lot!

Comment: You talking about this? http://handlebarsjs.com/precompilation.html

Comment: @EthanWelborn I'm sorry no, handlebarsjs renders templates in runtime. I need a tool to output the html files with rendered templates. Do you have any idea?

Comment: unfortunately I was unable to find anything that really fit what you were looking for. Probably wouldn't be too hard to write one, especially if there is no back-end logic behind it, just embedding html in other html.